# posterior predictive distribution from brms (logistic regression)

Tags: r, stan

I'm new to both `stan` and `brms`, and having trouble extracting posterior predictive distributions. Let's say I have a simple logistic regression

```
fit = brm(y ~ x, family="bernoulli", data=df.training)
```

where `y` is binary and `x` continuous. For test data (or even the training data), I thought I could now get hold of the predictive distribution for the bernoulli probability `p`, by altering `probs` in

```
predict(fit, df.test, probs=seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

However, while the output from this command gives me estimates that are continuous in the range `[0,1]` (this makes sense), the confidence interval values seem to be binary (this does not make sense to me)... How do I get the entire posterior predictive distribution for `p`?

Comment: Use the `posterior_predict` function.

Comment: that still returned binary values, however, `posterior_linpred(transform=TRUE)` actually did what I want... I guess this is only an issue for models where the observables are on a different scale than the actual response variable.

Comment: There's also the `pp_check` function that makes some pretty plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is obviously a long time ago. But I stumbled upon it and think it resonates with my own questions.

Based on my experiment on a logistic regression model I think below is true for the default inputs:

1. `posterior_linpred` gave the continuous linear scale;
2. `fitted` gave the continuous probability scale between 0 and 1;
3. `predict` gave the binary [0,1] scale predictions

I don't have a Beta-Binomial model (to me, it is a good example of logistic with over-dispersion) at hand to test what the result of the `posterior_linpred` would be, but I am confident that the `fitted` and `predict` would be on the outcome scale.

Comment: thanks for adding that answer despite the age, that should be a really good starting point for anyone facing similar issue in the future!